# How to get list of browser permissions

Tags: javascript, browser

I would like to know if there is a way to query the following permissions in Chrome:

```
accelerometer
camera
clipboard-read
clipboard-write
geolocation
background-sync
magnetometer
microphone
midi
notifications
payment-handler
persistent-storage
```

Thank you.

Comment: There's MDN documentation on this with a code example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `navigator.permissions`
Here is an example for the "geolocation":

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {
 if (result.state == 'granted') {
   showLocalNewsWithGeolocation();
 } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
   showButtonToEnableLocalNews();
 }
 // Don't do anything if the permission was denied.
});
```

you can read more from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query).